# Gravity form wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using gravity form in wordpress with ajax.
It is working fine when all field are correct.
When I submit form it show a ajax spinner and show success message.
But when there is some error in any field, it show validation errors after spin. 
But after it does nothing. Even if we correct all the fields it is not working.
PLease help

Comment: I solved it.
In get_form_button($form_id, $button_input_id, $button, $default_text, $class, $alt, $target_page_number) functon  

Change following Lines

Comment: Change following Lines
    $set_submitting = "window[\"gf_submitting_{$form_id}\"]=true;";
    $onclick="onclick='if(window[\"gf_submitting_{$form_id}\"])
    {return false;}  $set_submitting '";
To
    $set_submitting = "window[\"gf_submitting_{$form_id}\"]=true;";
    if(isset($_POST["gform_ajax"])){$ajax_submit = "window[\"gf_submitting_{$form_id}\"]=false;";}else{$ajax_submit = "";}onclick="onclick='$ajax_submit if(window[\"gf_submitting_{$form_id}\"]){return false;}  $set_submitting '";

Comment: Editing the plugin is not the best solution as changes will be lost during updates, and you should always update to the latest versions of WordPress and plugins. Your page most likely has one or more JavaScript errors which were preventing the Gravity Forms scripts from functioning correctly. Did you try working through a theme/plugin conflict test to narrow down the cause: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Testing_for_a_Theme/Plugin_Conflict